# Codeigniter 3, works on 'http' but not on 'https'

Tags: php, codeigniter, .htaccess

My htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|uploads|images|ws|vendor|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

I have also hidden my index.php

Fails to load: -
https://www.abc.in/abc-xyz-fdg

Works: -
https://www.abc.in/index.php/abc-xyz-fdg

Comment: Did you change base_url in config.php file `$config['base_url']`.

Comment: Please check this on page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42625147/how-to-force-ssl-in-codeigniter

Comment: @BalasahebBhise this did not work too

Comment: @GufranHasan `$config['base_url'] = "https://www.abc.in/"`

Comment: @shasha1589, yes right, you can also try this solution https://sajjadhossain.com/2008/10/27/ssl-https-urls-and-codeigniter/

Comment: @GufranHasan: I tried it but did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

**Step 1**

SSL config (which runs with https)

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
   AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

**Step 2**

The .htaccess file should be like this...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on      
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Reference link :
[HTTPS and Remove index.php on CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38952095/https-and-remove-index-php-on-codeigniter)

Thank you guys who tried to him me

Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make changes in two files.

1. `config.php` file `$config['secure_base_url']=" https://www.abc.in/"`;
2. And open the `url_helper.php` file `(system/helpers/url_helper.php)` and alter the code in https://sajjadhossain.com/2008/10/27/ssl-https-urls-and-codeigniter/
3. Now, add the following code in `Config.php` file `(system/Core/Config.php)` as in https://sajjadhossain.com/2008/10/27/ssl-https-urls-and-codeigniter/

[reference](https://sajjadhossain.com/2008/10/27/ssl-https-urls-and-codeigniter/)

Comment: `(system/libraries/Config.php)` I do not have this file?

Comment: Which version of CI you are using?

Comment: If you are using latest version v3.1.9then it would be in `system/Core/Config.php`.

Comment: I am Using 3.1.9. I just downloaded a new version of CI to Check if file was missing in mine. Its not there in the new download.

Comment: I made the necessary changes, but still not help

Comment: @shasha1589, Did you try this solution https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-64181.html?

Comment: All the solutions redirect to HTTPS, but my issue is  when the site is on HTTPS i need to add index.php in my URL to work. I don't need index.php in my URL for HTTPS

Comment: okay first you need to remove index.php from url. https://www.codexworld.com/how-to/remove-index-php-from-url-codeigniter-htaccess/